# How do I create "or'ed" switches using typedef enum?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, enums, typedef

I kinda like `enums`.  Their syntax is arcane-looking, and I've yet to find a definitive point of reference on their undeniably  proper use.. but let's say I had..

```
typedef enum {
    OrientTop,
    OrientBottom,
    OrientFiesta
}   Orient;
```

I'd love to be able, as I do with, for example, other constants when multiple chocies may be applicable/ required, just do…

```
 self.orientation = OrientTop | OrientFiesta;  // NO NO WORK-O!
```

just like one does with…

```
self.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
```

or also..

```
it = [[NSThing alloc]initOptions: NSStupid | NSSpicy | NSSassy];
```

and it would also be nice.. instead of…

```
 if ((o == OrientTop ) || ( o == OrientBottom))
```

i could just use…

```
if (o == OrientTop || OrientBottom)
```

<strike>and most importantly… how to check multiple cases, á la..</strike>

```
switch (orientation) {
    case OrientTop | OrientBottom:
```

<strike>Or something, of the sort..</strike>
ugh, oh.. you guys are too slow.. so, duh.. i just need to…

```
case OrientLeft:
case OrientRight:  { // blah blah blah
     break;        }
```

(But for the first part.. ) What is the extra "secret sauce" that Apple / smarter people than me.. are using to give their `typedef`'s  that extra zing that make mine taste so, ech..bland.. in comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as if `typedef`s such as `NSViewWidthSizable` are actually bitmasks, which allow the nice ORing operations you so enjoy.  In the headers for some `UIKit` elements, you can see what I mean:

```
enum {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;
```

I snatched that right off a [very helpful site that explains in more detail](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/bit-masks/), but you can also examine the enumeration of any constant by holding <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and clicking the constant or typedef.

Comment: Adding: The secret sauce is C. Objective-C is C with Smalltalk-style messaging, but it's still C with plenty of C. See?

Comment: Wow that webpage you linked to is a: totally relevant, b: mind-numbingly detailed, and c: shockingly hard to comprehend, despite being quite conscious in it's attempt to simplify the topic. let me just get my head around this and I'll be back, lol.